# Social login when app becomes active after suspension state

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, access-token

I have been struggling with this question and cannot seem to find a clean answer for. I am using social login in an app I am writing (my first). After the app launch, the user gets authenticated with his choice of a social network, in particular, Facebook.  when a user suspends the IOS app for days, and returns to it, the app returns right where the user left off, away from the initial login mechanism and the login viewController. How and where do you attempt to verify if the user Facebook token changed (due to password change) or expired? from what I understand you have to make a social graph api request, but does that mean I have to implement this request in every viewController in my app? I am under the impression that when the app becomes active it will only load the viewController displayed before the suspension. Maybe I am wrong.
your input is greatly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

So I do have controller over what I present when an app becomes active. I can simply present in the window the login view controller. I can silently verify the credentials. if pass present the next view controller. if not present the login page for the user interaction.
cheers